# Using DNS to serve different services on the same server that run on different ports

Tags: dns

I realize this is an extremely broad question, but I really need some direction. 
I have two services running on a server, using ports 50080 and 50090.  This was done due to the fact that, when creating the services in Java, running them on the same port created a conflict.

DNS was set up on the server to return the service running on 50080.  Basically, when you type in the domain name (prod.example.com), you'll get the get all method on that service by default. However, we would like to set up the DNS to account for the service on 50090.  I imagine this would work as running prod.example.com:50080 to go to the first service, and prod.example.com:50090 for the second service.

So far, I haven't found much documentation on how to achieve this.  It seems like it should be feasible to do this, but I'm drawing a blank on how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

If you are outside the web world you have the perfect solution for this, it is called `SRV` records. They are basically a generalization of what `MX` records did for email.

But first note that if you are in the web world, no browsers are using those records unfortunately, and hence probably no HTTP(S) client library either. In that case you indeed need to hardcode the port number in the URL, otherwise clients will go by default to 80 or 443. Or use some kind of proxying/redirection mechanism at the HTTP level.

So, if you are not in the web paradigm, go see [RFC 2782](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2782) for the definition of SRV record, or [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRV_record) for a gentler introduction to it.

In short they provide a way to decouple the identification of a service (which is a service name and a transport) to its location (which is basically an host name and a port), with some other properties thrown in, such as being able to do load-balancing/fail-over.

Let us say that you have two services running on the same box on different ports. But you do not want to hardcode any of that, especially at client side, because any service could be moved to another box or port at any time.

So you do it like that:

- you define service names, like `foo` and `bar`.
- let us say they work over TCP (or TLS)
- one on port `50080` the other on port `50090`

You can then publish in your DNS:

```
_foo._tcp.example.com. IN SRV 10 10 50080 somehost.example.com.
_bar._tcp.example.com. IN SRV 10 10 50090 somehost.example.com.
```

Then you just need to make sure the clients of these 2 services are using there SRV records, in order to find out the correct host name and port number to use to connect to get access to each service.
All of this would be invisible to the servers, it is just some logic to put in the clients.